# как сделать чтобы первая строка удалялась только если в начале запроса есть символ | Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

есть textarea с `@keydown.ctrl.\="newLine"` в которой выводится запрос. При нажатии хоткея, если запрос начинается с символа `|` то происходит перенос на другую строчку символа и содержимого после него, `slice(1)` используется с целью убрать пустую строку которая появляется перед всем запросом. - все работает как нужно

Но если запрос начинается с буквы, а не символа, обрезка не нужна.

Как сделать чтобы первая строка удалялась только если в начале запроса есть символ `|`?

Вот метод, который я использую

```js
newLine () {
  this.dsFormData.queryString = this.dsFormData.queryString.split('|').join('\n\|').slice(1);
},
```

Comment: рабочий вариант

newLine () {
      let line = this.dsFormData.queryString.split('|').join('\n\|');
      
      if (this.dsFormData.queryString[0] == "|") {
        this.dsFormData.queryString = line.slice(1);
      } else {
        this.dsFormData.queryString = line;
      } 
    },

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать чтобы первая строка удалялась только если в начале запроса есть символ `|`?

Можно сразу разобраться со строкой и потом применить выше указанный алгоритм "разбиения".

```js
let str = '|123|456'
const re = /^\|/
if (re.test(str)) str = str.replace(re, '')
console.log(str)
// далее по приведенному алгоритму
```